# jQuery dropdown and buttons changing disabled property for each pair

Tags: html, jquery, select, button, dropdown

I currently have two sets of drop down boxes with values in and a button next to it:
[image: Dropdown and button]

The drop down has a class of **.select-tickets**
The add button has a class of **.add-to-basket**

If there is no value in the box I want the button to be disabled. (Upon page load all buttons are disabled).

If there is a value in the box I want the button to be enabled.

The jQuery code I am currently using is:

```
$(".select-tickets").change(function() {
          if (this.value > 0) {
            $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.add-to-basket').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.add-to-basket').prop("disabled", true);
          };  
 });
```

This works fine, however If I enter a value in the top dropdown box, both "Add" buttons become enabled and vice versa. I would like each pair to act individually from the other pairs of dropdown and button

How do I make this code work on each individual set of dropdown and buttons (I would like to avoid adding an id or seperate class to each one as I may have end up with 20+ sets of dropdown boxes and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working (with help from a friend) so the code is now:

```
    $(".rhs-select-tickets").change(function () {
    if (this.value > 0) {
        $(this).parents('.rhs-price-type-selection-container').find('.rhs-inline-select-btn').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.rhs-price-type-selection-container').find('.rhs-inline-select-btn').prop("disabled", true);
    };
});
```